# Remove duplicate entries given certain criteria using the tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following example data:

```r
library(dplyr)
d <- tibble("ID" = rep(c(1111, 2222, 3333, 4444), each = 4),
            "DAY" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
            "FINISHED" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0))
```

I want to remove one entry from participants (`ID`) who completed a given day's survey (`DAY`) twice. Specifically I want to remove that row (or rows, if completed 3+ times in a given day) where they did not finish the entire survey (`FINISHED == 0`).

Is this possible to do with `group_by`? Any `tidyverse` solution is welcome.

**Expected output** (row 7 removed):

```r
# A tibble: 16 x 3
      ID   DAY FINISHED
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  1111     1        1
 2  1111     2        1
 3  1111     3        1
 4  1111     4        1
 5  2222     1        1
 6  2222     2        1
 8  2222     3        1
 9  3333     1        1
10  3333     2        1
11  3333     3        1
12  3333     4        1
13  4444     1        1
14  4444     2        1
15  4444     3        1
16  4444     4        0
```

---

**EDIT:**

If a participant takes a given day's survey 2+ times and finishes both (`FINISH == 1`), I would like to remove the earliest completion (i.e., keep the date closest to today). Here's an extended example dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
d <- tibble("ID" = rep(c(1111, 2222, 3333, 4444), each = 4),
            "DAY" = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
            "FINISHED" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
            "DATE" = as_date(c("2019-08-01", "2019-08-02", "2019-08-03", "2019-08-04",
                       "2019-08-01", "2019-08-02", "2019-08-02", "2019-08-03",
                       "2019-08-01", "2019-08-02", "2019-08-03", "2019-08-04",
                       "2019-08-01", "2019-08-02", "2019-08-03", "2019-08-04")))
```

And the expected output (rows 3, 7 removed):

```r
# A tibble: 16 x 4
      ID   DAY FINISHED DATE      
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <date>    
 1  1111     1        1 2019-08-01
 2  1111     2        1 2019-08-02
 4  1111     3        1 2019-08-04
 5  2222     1        1 2019-08-01
 6  2222     2        1 2019-08-02
 8  2222     3        1 2019-08-03
 9  3333     1        1 2019-08-01
10  3333     2        1 2019-08-02
11  3333     3        1 2019-08-03
12  3333     4        1 2019-08-04
13  4444     1        1 2019-08-01
14  4444     2        1 2019-08-02
15  4444     3        1 2019-08-03
16  4444     4        0 2019-08-04
```

Comment: @RonakShah Just did that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's not tidyverse, but `d[!(duplicated(d[c("ID","DAY")]) & d$FINISHED == 0),]` - I suspect that could be shoe-horned into `filter()` if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `ID` and `DAY` and remove rows where group has more than one row and `FINISHED == 0`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
  group_by(ID, DAY) %>%
  filter(!(n() > 1 & FINISHED == 0))

#      ID   DAY FINISHED
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1  1111     1        1
# 2  1111     2        1
# 3  1111     3        1
# 4  1111     4        1
# 5  2222     1        1
# 6  2222     2        1
# 7  2222     3        1
# 8  3333     1        1
# 9  3333     2        1
#10  3333     3        1
#11  3333     4        1
#12  4444     1        1
#13  4444     2        1
#14  4444     3        1
#15  4444     4        0
```

---

Using same logic in base R `ave`

```
d[!with(d, ave(FINISHED == 0, ID, DAY, FUN = function(x) length(x) > 1 & x == 0)), ]
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, .SD[!(.N > 1 & FINISHED == 0)], by = .(ID, DAY)]
```

---

**EDIT**

For the updated data, we can add another `&` condition

```
d %>%
  group_by(ID, DAY) %>%
  dplyr::filter(!(n() > 1 & FINISHED == 0) &
                !(n() > 1 & all(FINISHED == 1) & DATE == min(DATE)))

#      ID   DAY FINISHED DATE      
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <date>    
# 1  1111     1        1 2019-08-01
# 2  1111     2        1 2019-08-02
# 3  1111     3        1 2019-08-04
# 4  2222     1        1 2019-08-01
# 5  2222     2        1 2019-08-02
# 6  2222     3        1 2019-08-03
# 7  3333     1        1 2019-08-01
# 8  3333     2        1 2019-08-02
# 9  3333     3        1 2019-08-03
#10  3333     4        1 2019-08-04
#11  4444     1        1 2019-08-01
#12  4444     2        1 2019-08-02
#13  4444     3        1 2019-08-03
#14  4444     4        0 2019-08-04
```

Comment: Thank you, this works beautifully. I edited my answer to include a level of complexity that I am now dealing with. Are you able to extend your `dplyr` response to incorporate this new info?

Comment: @Ronak_Shah re: the `min(DATE)` piece, what if there are 3 entries on a given day and I need to remove the bottom two dates? This will only remove the first (minimum date) submission. TIA.

Comment: @Brigadeiro You could use `max` in that case. `d %>%
  group_by(ID, DAY) %>%
  dplyr::filter(!(n() > 1 & FINISHED == 0) &
                !(n() > 1 & all(FINISHED == 1) & DATE != max(DATE)))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way in `dplyr` that filters out duplicated `DAY` with `FINISHED == 0` for only the `ID`s having 3+ days. -

```
d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 3 & !(duplicated(DAY) & FINISHED == 0)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 15 x 3
      ID   DAY FINISHED
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  1111     1        1
 2  1111     2        1
 3  1111     3        1
 4  1111     4        1
 5  2222     1        1
 6  2222     2        1
 7  2222     3        1
 8  3333     1        1
 9  3333     2        1
10  3333     3        1
11  3333     4        1
12  4444     1        1
13  4444     2        1
14  4444     3        1
15  4444     4        0
```